# How to implement two buttons in the same activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-button

I've got two buttons in my initial activity and each button when clicked needs to move to a different activity. First button seems to be working fine, but the second button just halts the entire application. I've tried implementing all the solutions posted here, but nothing seems to work.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button ab;
Button ba;
Intent intent;
Intent intentt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);







    ab=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

    ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
    ba=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Intent intentt= new Intent();
    intentt.setClass(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity.class);

    ba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                    startActivity(intentt);


            }

    });

}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/a"
tools:context="com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Click on any one of the data sets from below"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />

    <activity android:name=".Main6Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

log:

```
03-25 22:25:24.410 32470-32470/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks, PID: 32470
                                                                                       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks.Main6Activity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1885)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1579)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3921)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3881)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4208)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4176)
                                                                                           at com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)

at.com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

03-25 22:25:26.248 32470-32470/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32470 SIG: 9
03-25 22:25:27.195 977-977/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks-2/lib/arm
03-25 22:25:33.868 977-977/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks-2/lib/arm
03-25 22:25:34.625 977-983/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.958ms
03-25 22:25:34.754 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-25 22:25:34.917 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks I/Adreno-EGL: : QUALCOMM Build: 10/09/15, 6cbbf7d, I3193f6e94a
03-25 22:25:34.921 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-25 22:25:37.932 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8e4e140
03-25 22:25:37.933 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb8fab560 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb8e11eb0
03-25 22:25:39.101 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8fbb720
03-25 22:25:39.101 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb8ec5cf0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb8e51df0
03-25 22:25:41.803 977-1423/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8e613a8
03-25 22:25:44.821 977-977/com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: A couple of comments: 1) You have two method variables, `intent` and `intentt` shadowing two class member variables with the same name. This is a bug waiting to happen. Use either the class or method variables. 2) Your variable names are very close and it will be easy to miss the second "t" in `intentt'. 3) If cleaning up the variables doesn't work, check to see if it is your activity that is causing the problem. You could, for instance, swap the activities on the buttons to see if the problem follows or not.

Comment: The `Main2Activity` and `Main6Activity` activities actually exist in your application? If so, could you post the code from them as well? The log suggests that it couldn't find the `Main6Activity` class.

Comment: @Cheticamp There seems to be an issue with Main6Activity.

Comment: @AlexFlorin They're blank activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Try to change this :**

```
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />

    <activity android:name=".Main6Activity"></activity>
```

to this in your manifest by **Refactoring** the Class names :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity_Two" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity_Six"></activity>
```

There might be a problem with the naming

**Alternatively try changing this in Your `MainActivity.java` class**

```
ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
    ba=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);



    ba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                   Intent intentt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intentt);


            }

    });
```

**Instead of :**

```
ab=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

    ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
    ba=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Intent intentt= new Intent();
    intentt.setClass(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity.class);

    ba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                    startActivity(intentt);


            }

    });
```

Comment: That was my initial code, but it didn't seemed to have worked. That's exactly why I had gone to setClass.

Comment: You are welcome , @Anon, so now the issue was at the class name

Comment: No need to change the activity class name. Its IDE generated name and seems Fine. I have tried with it and its working fine. I think there is no issue with class names. Thank you~

Comment: @how sure are we that you even tried it? Please see my answer below. I have added full source code here. Hope it will help you to believe. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of what you are trying to make:

1. Main Activity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Button btn1;
   private Button btn2;

   private void startMyActivity(Intent intent) {
       startActivity(intent);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


       btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
               startMyActivity(myIntent);
           }
       });

       btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
               startActivity(myIntent);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ngenh.stack.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"/>

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The other two activities are empty.

Some comments on your code:

1. Try not to name variables like built-in ones since you will shadow them.
2. If you see that the same code repeats with the only difference being a variable or two, try making a function for it.
3. Give specific names and ids (unlike what I did). Login button should be btnLogin or something like that, not button1, button2, etc.

Comment: Okey. :) make sure to vote their question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your attached error logs it seems your AndroidManifest.xml file is OK. Just `clean` and `build` your project again.

BTW, I have modified some of your code portion and its working fine. You can try this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonA;
    Button buttonB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);
        buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_b);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```
package com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

**Main6Activity.java**

```
package com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    tools:context="com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Click on any one of the data sets from below"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_a"
        android:text="B"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks.Main2Activity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main6.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks.Main6Activity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fryselectronics.knowyourbooks">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main6Activity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting it. :)

Comment: @Anon: If this answer helps to resolve your issue then don't forget to upvote and accept answer. Thank you~